# Parcelable - Cannot select from parameterized type

Tags: android, parcelable

In my Application I have class which contains a List of List to which I want to make `Parcelable` to particular class so far I have tried

```
public class FeaturesParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private List<List<SpinnerModel>> featuresSublist;

    public List<List<SpinnerModel>> getFeaturesSublist() {
        return featuresSublist;
    }

    public void setFeaturesSublist(List<List<SpinnerModel>> featuresSublist) {
        this.featuresSublist = featuresSublist;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(this.featuresSublist);
    }

    public FeaturesParcelable() {
    }

    protected FeaturesParcelable(Parcel in) {
        this.featuresSublist = new ArrayList<List<SpinnerModel>>();
        in.readList(this.featuresSublist, List<SpinnerModel>.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<FeaturesParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FeaturesParcelable>() {
        @Override
        public FeaturesParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new FeaturesParcelable(source);
        }

        @Override
        public FeaturesParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FeaturesParcelable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

but I getting an error **cannot select from parameterized** type inside

```
protected FeaturesParcelable(Parcel in) {
        this.featuresSublist = new ArrayList<List<SpinnerModel>>();
        in.readList(this.featuresSublist, List<SpinnerModel>.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

Comment: Because of how interfaces/generics work in Java, for starters you likely need a concrete List implementation rather than using the List<T> interface as you are above.

Answer (score 1):

1) `List<SpinnerModel>.class` does not resolve do the thing you expect. Java uses [generic type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), so the run-time type of that statement is `Class<List<?>>`. This is not enough to identify suitable implementation of `List` or the type of the list element.

2) Even if you overcome your initial difficulty (e.g. by replacing `List` with `ArrayList` and manually deserializing nested lists), you should be aware, that `List<SpinnerModel>.class.getClassLoader()` returns a *system ClassLoader*. System ClassLoader is hardcoded to load only Android framework classes; in order to deserialize classes, declared in your application, use ClassLoader assigned to them: `SpinnerModel.class.getClassLoader()`.